# Difference between "festa" and "vacanza" (holiday)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I am trying to understand what is the difference between "festa" and "vacanza" when they mean "holiday" (US term for a day in which most schools, stores and offices are closed because of a public celebration). I am aware of the other meanings of both words and I am not interested in them here.

From the relevant definitions of "[festa](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/festa/)" and "[vacanza](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vacanza/)" in the Treccani dictionary, I infer the following:

- festa: used when focusing on the solenity/celebration or on the object of celebration
- vacanza: used when focusing on the period of rest

Examples:

- Il 25 aprile è vacanza in tutte le scuole (not "festa")
- Domani è vacanza (not "festa")
- Domani è la festa della mamma (not "vacanza")
- Ci sono 15 feste religiose/nazionali durante l'anno. ("not vacanze")

Is that right or is there some overlap between both words?

Comment: Definitely, there is some overlap between these two words because you can also say "il 25 aprile è festa" and "domani è festa".

Comment: You can see at [Treccani Sinonimi e Contrari](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/festa_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) that "festa" can be what you have said in your question (point 1. a.), but also "giorno in cui non si lavora", that is, a synonym of "vacanza" (point 1. d.).

Comment: 19 March is traditionally considered “festa del papà” (St. Joseph’s feast in the Catholic calendar), but it's not a holiday (it used to be, a few decades ago).

Comment: Yes, @egreg, "festa" with the meaning of a day of celebration of a religious or civil solemnity doesn't imply that "most schools, stores and offices are closed" as stated in the question. A typical example from my country is "la festa di San Giorgio", a very important celebration in Catalonia which is a working day.

Comment: Example 1: you can't say "festa" because you specified "nelle scuole" (one would imagine student parties), we are not in the meanings overlap scenario described; example 2: you can use both terms; example 3: that's not "vacanza", as described by egreg; example 4: both are ok ("vacanze" would be a bit colloquial), but normally one would use "festività"

Comment: @OldManofAran: Nevertheless, in this [newspaper headline](https://iltirreno.gelocal.it/versilia/cronaca/2019/02/01/news/l-appello-di-marialina-il-martedi-grasso-sia-festa-nelle-scuole-1.17713719), «Il martedì grasso sia festa nelle scuole», the word "festa" seems to have the same meaning as "vacanza". Anyway, I admit the espression "festa nelle scuole", without any context, is ambiguous.

Comment: off-topic: what does "grasso" mean in the example of the last comment? I am not able to understand the sentence.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista:  [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mardi_Gras) is the meaning of "martedì grasso".

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are quite right, I would find it strange if someone doesn't understand you, but I have something to add to them:

- "Il 25 aprile è festa in tutta Italia, quindi le scuole sono chiuse" (I wouldn't use "vacanza" here for a reason explained in the next example).
- it's better to say "domani è festa" rather than "domani è vacanza" (as already said in comments), because "vacanza" focuses on a period longer than one day (usually).
- third example is perfect.
- "Ci sono 15 festività religiose/nazionali durante l'anno" in fact if you use "feste" here it seems that you mean it like "feasts/parties"

They are usually not overlapping in meaning (but of course it depends on the context) and I believe that you got the differences between the two terms.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE and thank you for your answer! Note that "Il 25 aprile è vacanza in tutte le scuole" is an example from [Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vacanza).

Comment: Apart from this, note that the OP is asking if there is some overlap between the meanings of these two words.

Comment: Thank you! I edited the answer.

Comment: Of course "Il 25 aprile è vacanza in tutte le scuole" is correct, but in spoken Italian I would rather use "Il 25 aprile le scuole sono chiuse per festa". But, as I said in the answer, it really depends on the context and on what we want to focus on, the celebration or the period.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is "festività" used for both religious and secular holidays?

Comment: Yes I would say so!